# How to log warning, error and other info in Odoo development?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, printing, odoo

Question: I want to log the warning in odoo logs if any warning or error comes up.

Is there any way out of it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Question is not really clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please user logger to print the logs in terminal

Try

> import logging

> *logger = logging.getLogger(_*_name__)

Use like this:-

> _logger.debug(" my log in terminal")